# Passing integer variable between python script and flask

Tags: variables, flask, import

First time posting and new at programming python so please bear with me.

I have been playing with 3 scripts for a product packing line project.  Basically there are 10 buttons that can be pressed, that keep a count of how many times they have been pressed in a Variable that I have put in a separate script (vars.py), I have a main script (pack.py) that does the majority of the work and finally I have a script with the flask app in (app.py)
My problem is, the variables will not come over to app.py and display.  If I change the variable manually then they show the contents happily.  But for some reason that I cant see, when the main script (pack.py) adds to the variables nothing changes..  Hope that makes sense.

So to me it looks like the main script reads the variable (0 at the start), adds 1 every time the buttons are pressed fine and I can print that number on the terminal window, but trying to read the variable into flask and display in html it shows the original variable (zero).

How can I get the current count from the variable and send it to flask or get flask to retrieve it?

I have tried to add my code but the website separates it all up and it looks a real mess but will keep trying.

I get the feeling that Flask only uses the first imported variable rather than the current one, how do I get around this in python?

EDIT:  This is the script that deals with flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sys
from vars import *
app = Flask('PackingDisplay')

@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('display.html', variable1=buttonpress1, 
   variable2=buttonpress2, variable3=buttonpress3, 
   variable4=buttonpress4, variable5=buttonpress5, 
   variable6=buttonpress6, variable7=buttonpress7, 
   variable8=buttonpress8, variable9=buttonpress9, 
   variable10=buttonpress10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='10.10.10.102', port=5000)
```

This is the variable store script-:

```
buttonpress1 = 0 #Set station 1 count to zero
buttonpress2 = 0 #Set station 2 count to zero
buttonpress3 = 0 #Set station 3 count to zero
buttonpress4 = 0 #Set station 4 count to zero
buttonpress5 = 0 #Set station 5 count to zero
buttonpress6 = 0 #Set station 6 count to zero
buttonpress7 = 0 #Set station 7 count to zero
buttonpress8 = 0 #Set station 8 count to zero
buttonpress9 = 0 #Set station 9 count to zero
buttonpress10 = 0 #Set station 10 count to zero
```

and this is part of the main script-:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
import os
import sys
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from time import sleep

import vars

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Station 1 button GPIO 
pin
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Station 2 button GPIO 
pin
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Station 3 button GPIO 
pin
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Station 4 button GPIO 
pin
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Station 5 button GPIO 
pin
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Station 6 button GPIO 
pin
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Station 7 button GPIO 
pin
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Station 8 button GPIO 
pin
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Station 9 button GPIO 
pin
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Station 10 button 
GPIO pin
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Start/Stop packing 
run button  
GPIO.setup(14,GPIO.OUT) # Red and Green status LED's on pin 14

def main(): 

print("System Booted, waiting...")
GPIO.output(14, True)
GPIO.wait_for_edge(13, GPIO.FALLING)
sleep(0.5)
GPIO.output(14, False)

wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.column_dimensions['A'].width = 12 # Set column width in excel
ws1["A1"] = "Date"
ws1["B1"] = "Time"
ws1["C1"] = "Station 1"
ws1["D1"] = "Station 2"
ws1["E1"] = "Station 3"
ws1["F1"] = "Station 4"
ws1["G1"] = "Station 5"
ws1["H1"] = "Station 6"
ws1["I1"] = "Station 7"
ws1["J1"] = "Station 8"
ws1["K1"] = "Station 9"
ws1["L1"] = "Station 10"

# now we'll define the threaded callback functions for each packing station
def my_callback1(channel):
    print("Station 1 Button Pressed")
    global buttonpress1
    print(buttonpress1 +1, "Times")
    buttonpress1 += 1
def my_callback2(channel):
    print("Station 2 Button Pressed")
    global buttonpress2
    print(buttonpress2 +1, "Times")
    buttonpress2 += 1
    
def my_callback3(channel):
    print("Station 3 Button Pressed")
    vars.buttonpress3
    print(vars.buttonpress3 +1, "Times")
    vars.buttonpress3 += 1
    
def my_callback4(channel):
    print("Station 4 Button Pressed")
    global buttonpress4
    print(buttonpress4 +1, "Times")
    buttonpress4 += 1
def my_callback5(channel):
    print("Station 5 Button Pressed")
    global buttonpress5
    print(buttonpress5 +1, "Times")
    buttonpress5 += 1
def my_callback6(channel):
    print("Station 6 Button Pressed")
    global buttonpress6
    print(buttonpress6 +1, "Times")
    buttonpress6 += 1
def my_callback7(channel):
    print("Station 7 Button Pressed")
    global buttonpress7
    print(buttonpress7 +1, "Times")
    buttonpress7 += 1
def my_callback8(channel):
    print("Station 8 Button Pressed")
    global buttonpress8
    print(buttonpress8 +1, "Times")
    buttonpress8 += 1
def my_callback9(channel):
    print("Station 9 Button Pressed")
    global buttonpress9
    print(buttonpress9 +1, "Times")
    buttonpress9 += 1
def my_callback10(channel):
    print("Station 10 Button Pressed")
    global buttonpress10
    print(buttonpress10 +1, "Times")
    buttonpress10 += 1

GPIO.add_event_detect(1, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback1, bouncetime=3000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback2, bouncetime=3000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(5, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback3, bouncetime=3000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(6, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback4, bouncetime=3000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(7, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback5, bouncetime=3000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(8, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback6, bouncetime=3000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(9, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback7, bouncetime=3000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(10, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback8, bouncetime=3000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(11, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback9, bouncetime=3000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(12, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback10, bouncetime=3000)
try:
    print("New packing run started, Waiting for end of packing run button and listening for station buttons")
    sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(14, False)
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(13, GPIO.FALLING)
    print("End of packing run")
    sleep(0.5) # Delay in seconds
    
    print(vars.buttonpress3, "TEST READ VAR")
    
    GPIO.output(14, False)
    sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(14, True)
    sleep(0.5) # Delay in seconds

    # Create, Load the workbook and select the sheet
    timestr = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S")
    file_name = "PackingRun-"+timestr+".xlsx"     
    ws1.title = "CountsData"
    date = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S")

    # update data to excel sheet
    row = (date, timestamp, vars.buttonpress1, vars.buttonpress2, vars.buttonpress3, vars.buttonpress4,
           vars.buttonpress5, vars.buttonpress6, buttonpress7, buttonpress8, buttonpress9, buttonpress10)
    ws1.append(row)
    time.sleep(1)
     
    # Save the workbook
    wb.save(f"/home/pi/share/{file_name}")
    
    # Wait for start packing run button press
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(13, GPIO.FALLING)

    # Restart the function for next packing run
    sys.stdout.flush()
    os.execl(sys.executable, 'python', __file__, *sys.argv[1:])

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()       # clean up GPIO on CTRL+C exit

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: Do you have code samples?  It's important to know how you're executing or importing each .py file and how you're referencing your variables from script to script.

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to add my code but the system wants to split up all my code into chunks that dont make sense.  So I will try and add some parts separately.

Comment: Yay, figured out how to post my code..